# Парсинг определенного текста из файла

Tags: c++

Нужно из файла [(вот его текст)](http://pastebin.com/SW9tJdh6) спарсить только что, что находится между тегом `<keyMaterial> </keyMaterial>`. Как можно это реализовать на С++?

//UPD.
Проблему решил таким образом:

```
// ConsoleApplication11.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("{1AC815AC-7555-48FB-B768-9E171453FE23}.xml");

    {
        std::string s;
        s.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs.rdbuf())), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        size_t begin = s.find("<keyMaterial>") + 13;
        size_t end = s.find("</keyMaterial>");
        s = s.substr(begin, end - begin);
        std::cout << s;
        ifs.close();
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вбить в гугл "C++ XML parser" и выбрать тот, который больше понравится.

Comment: Что вы в данном случае понимаете под "спарсить"? там просто длинная строка - что вы хотите получить?

Comment: @Harry нужно все, что находится в теге (01000000D.....E426F).

Comment: Раз решили - постите ответ, может быть еще кому пригодится.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
  try {
    std::ifstream ifs("{1AC815AC-7555-48FB-B768-9E171453FE23}.xml");
    std::stringstream sstream;
    sstream << ifs.rdbuf();
    std::string str = sstream.str();
    std::regex rx("(?:.|\\n|\\r)*?<keyMaterial>(.+?)</keyMaterial>(?:.|\\n\\r)*");
    std::smatch match;
    if(!(std::regex_search(str, match, rx) && match.size()==2)) 
      throw std::runtime_error("Substring not found!");
    std::cout << match[1] << std::endl;
  } catch(std::runtime_error &e) {
    std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  } catch(...) {
    std::cout << "Some error!" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```